# Flask-login token loader

Tags: python, session, authentication, flask

I'm setting up a Flask app with the flask-login extension. The flask-login documentation recommends setting up an alternative token generator that does not simply use the user ID and app secret to create the session token (which is the default method). But it doesn't provide any clear recommendations for how to do this.

So, for `User.get_auth_token()`, I'm using the `make_secure_token` function with the user email and password as parameters (so I get a hash of these parameters + app secret).

Next, I need to be able to get the user from the token with the `token_loader` callback. The default method for generating tokens in flask-login is to include both the raw user ID and a hash of the user ID + app secret. That makes finding the user from the token pretty simple - just grab the ID and look up the user.

But should I be exposing the user ID in the session token at all? If I don't, should I store the session token in the database or somewhere else with the user ID to make a lookup possible?

In short: does anyone know what the best practice is for creating a secure token & corresponding `token_loader` callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Flask mailing list, Matt Wright pointed me to [his implementation](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/develop/flask_security/core.py#L94) in the flask-security extension. He uses [itsdangerous](http://packages.python.org/itsdangerous/) to create a signed token which encodes a serialized (via [`URLSafeTimedSerializer()`](http://packages.python.org/itsdangerous/#itsdangerous.URLSafeTimedSerializer)) list consisting of the user ID and the password hash. The token can then be decoded to grab the user ID.